# How to improve model's accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow

My model has one hidden layer having 100 neurons, I have used sigmoid as an activation function and in last layer I used softmax. I want to classify my data into two classes. Output layer has two neurons. Can someone please guide me what should I do to improve my model's accuracy?

```
`step: 9000, train_acc: 0.82,test_acc: 0.765
step: 9100, train_acc: 0.67,test_acc: 0.72
step: 9200, train_acc: 0.66,test_acc: 0.674
step: 9300, train_acc: 0.75,test_acc: 0.737
step: 9400, train_acc: 0.61,test_acc: 0.613
step: 9500, train_acc: 0.82,test_acc: 0.712
step: 9600, train_acc: 0.81,test_acc: 0.765
step: 9700, train_acc: 0.77,test_acc: 0.773
step: 9800, train_acc: 0.76,test_acc: 0.758
step: 9900, train_acc: 0.72,test_acc: 0.75`
```

Comment: Are you feeding it one example per training step? That's what it looks like to me...

Comment: Yes you have pointed out right mistake. But how did you guess by looking at the output that I am feeding one example?

Comment: Mainly accuracy being either 1 or 0 (1/1 or 0/1). If you had 2 examples, one would expect some 0.5s. The more examples, the more varied accuracy.

Comment: I want to classify data into 2 classes. I have 2 output neurons. On 1st hidden layer I use sigmoid as activaton And on outermost layer I used softmax. When I replace softmax with sigmoid my network shows 99 percent accuray but with softmax accuracy is low. But I can't use sigmoid at output layer because I comapre accuracy of my model by tf.argmax. Can you please point out why it is so?